# "expression not allowed in userFilter" gooddata api

Tags: json, gooddata

I'm receiving this response when I try to create a user filter in the GoodData API, does anybody knows what is this error and how to solve it?

```
{
   "error" : {
      "parameters" : [
         "[/gdc/md/PROJECT_ID/obj/OBJECT_ID]=[/gdc/md/PROJECT_ID/obj/OBJECT_ID/elements?id=ELEMENT_ID] OR [/gdc/md/PROJECT_ID/obj/OBJECT_ID]=[/gdc/md/PROJECT_ID/obj/OBJECT_ID/elements?id=ELEMENT_ID]"
      ],
      "requestId" : "REQUEST_ID",
      "component" : "Resource::Obj::Service",
      "errorClass" : "GDC::Exception::User",
      "message" : "Expression not allowed in userFilter '%s'."
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I was picking the wrong id, I was using de url value instead the "formOf" value found in the /gdc/md/PROJECT_ID/obj/OBJECT_ID

Comment: Hello João, I believe it has solve the issue. Is that correct? Thanks Filip

Comment: Hello Filip, yes, I think that the message should be different indicating that I was trying to use an incorrect ID. But fortunately it was solved. Thank you.